# When using module exports, why is an instance exported instead of the class itself? (How to export a constructor)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a file which contains the following:

```
var Foo = function() {};
Foo.prototype.bar = function() { return "hello world" }
export default function() {
  return new Foo();
}
```

In another file, I can then import this like so:

```
import Foo from "./my_other_file.js";
var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bar());
// => "hello world"
```

It took me a while to get this working. The specific thing I was confused about is `export default function() { return new Foo() }`. My initial inclination was to `return Foo` (in other words, return the class itself instead of an instance).

It seems redundant to have to initialize the class twice (once when exporting and once after importing). This isn't the first time I've come across this type of thing - I've also seen it when using inheritance.

My question is - why is this the case? It seems non-intuitive to me, so I'm hoping there's a good reason for it.

Comment: I don't understand why you have two functions in the first place.

Comment: @zeroflagL I don't really understand your confusion. Which two functions? And why not?

Comment: `Foo` and the function you export. The latter is pointless in this example.

Comment: @zeroflagL I'm trying to separate my code into separate files.

Comment: Both functions are in the same file. I was referring to your first code snippet.

Comment: @zeroflagL When I posted the question, I wasn't aware of a better way to do it. Is that what you mean by "pointless" - that it was naive? Regardless of whether it's "pointless", I was seeking an explanation for why exporting `new Foo()` didn't pass an instance to the other file. I understand that `return Foo` _wouldn't_ pass the constructor, and I'm still not clear why.

Comment: "pointless" means that the function doesn't serve any purpose. If you export `Foo` as default you get the same result.

Comment: @zeroflagL alright, I realize that I was confused because I was using `var foo = new Foo();` when `var foo = Foo()` could have also been used, and I was confused because of that. I've got it figured out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this the case?

The module does not export the `Foo` constructor directly, but only a factory function that creates a new `Foo` instance. Notice that it does not export an instance itself (as your question title suggests).

The advantage of this is that you can omit the `new` keyword and also do

```
import Foo from "./my_other_file.js";
var foo = Foo(); // <==
console.log(foo.bar());
```

The disadvantage is of course that you cannot easily subclass or extend the class.

> My initial inclination was to `return Foo`

No, you should not export a function that returns the class (constructor function). You should simply export the class itself directly, using `export {Foo as default}` or

```
export default function Foo() {};
Foo.prototype.bar = function() { return "hello world" };
```

(or `export default class Foo {…}` in ES6, of course).

Comment: you say `of course` a few times, but I don't feel the same sense of obviousness. Perhaps you could explain these points a bit more thoroughly.

Comment: @maxpleaner: The first "of course": Without direct access to the `Foo` class from outside the module, code that needs/wants to subclass it or mix in some methods is a lot more complicated. You might simply not need that, but if one does then exporting the class next to the default export is trivial. The second "of course": If you are using ES6 modules, I'd have expected you to use ES6 syntax for classes as well. It's still equivalent to the other two options I've mentioned though.

Answer (score 1):

I usually view the file in which I define my EMCAScript6 classes as something like the a class file in my C# Api.

In your case you'd do this in the Foo-Class file, to define your class:

```
export default class Foo {
    bar() {
        return "hello world"
    }
}
```

The other file stays the same.

This way you don't have to create two instances of the class. You just have to create the instance where you use it.

If you just want the Foo file to return a function that returns "hello world", you'd do this

```
export default function() {
    return "hello world";
}
```

And then use Foo in the other file like a function.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet above presupposes that there's an importer (e.g. framework application) that expects factory function instead of constructor:

```
import fooFactory from from "./my_other_file.js";

// launches a function and throws on constructors
fooConsumer(fooFactory);
```

Any way, it is always good idea to maintain both `default` (as the export at hand) and named exports.

```
export var Foo = function() {};
Foo.prototype.bar = function() { return "hello world" }
export default function() {
  return new Foo();
}
```

Even if named exports aren't used in the app now, they may be useful later (for testing).